# Why can I create iterator of values from Vec and not from array?

Tags: arrays, rust, vector, ownership

The code below compiles, but if the `args` passed to the function `f` is changed from a vector of strings to an array of strings it does not. I'm trying to understand why. I assume it has something to do with the ownership rules, but I could use some clarification.

```
fn f(args: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=String>>) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("{}", arg)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args = vec!["one_arg".to_string()]; // If changed to array, I get error below
    f(Box::new(args.into_iter()));
}
```

If `vec!["one_arg".to_string()]` is changed to `["one_arg".to_string()]`, I get the error below:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, std::string::String> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == std::string::String`
  --> src/main.rs:10:7
   |
10 |     f(Box::new(args.into_iter()));
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::string::String`
           found reference `&std::string::String`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = std::string::String>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because `Vec::into_iter` returns an iterator over its items, while `slice::into_iter` returns an iterator over references to its items. So, `args.into_iter()` is an `Iterator<Item=&String>` instead of `Iterator<Item=String>` when `args` is a slice. On a side note, don't `Box` a `dyn Iterator` and instead just use a generic:

```
fn f<I: Iterator<Item=String>>(args: I) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("{}", arg)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let args = vec!["one_arg".to_string()];
    f(args.into_iter());
}
```

Comment: OK. But my question then becomes (because I wasn't clear ;-) ), why? If I have to just accept it, I will, but why the different behavior? Does that mean objects in an array can never be moved? And thanks for the advice to use a generic, BTW.

Comment: @BillBarrington It's mostly a historical accident that's not easy to fix at this point: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65819

Comment: Yes, you cannot move values out of an array/slice in rust. If you want to simulate moving, you could use something like `mem::take`, which will replace a value with the default value and return the value taken.